# How to Get All Data along with Group BY Count in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

So I have table with ID, CustomerID, Name, Salary

Way I want data back is All Data with New Column that shows total of records group by CustomerID,

```
 ID        CustomerID    Name    Salary
  1            1          John    3000
  2            1          Kim     1000
  3            2          Sarah   2000
  4            2          Jim     4000
  5            2          Kane    2000 
  6            3          Bul     2500
```

So I want something like this, new column that show group by total of records,

```
  ID        CustomerID    Name    Salary   Count
  1            1          John    3000       2
  2            1          Kim     1000       2
  3            2          Sarah   2000       3
  4            2          Jim     4000       3
  5            2          Kane    2000       3
  6            3          Bul     2500       1
```

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for window functions, in this case, `count()`:

```
select t.*, count(*) over (partition by CustomerId) as cnt
from table t;
```

Comment: nice, much less verbose than my answer

Comment: this query is giving mr total number of records in new column, I need group by customerID total so forCustomer ID 1 there are 2 records so i should get 2 in last column, for CustomerID 2 there are 3 records and so on.

Comment: It actually worked, disregard Previous comment! Thanks a ton Goldon!

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
ID,CustomerID,Name,Salary, COUNT(CustomerID) Count
from tableName
group by ID,CustomerID,Name,Salary
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just join to a subquery that calculates the counts:

```
CREATE TABLE #customer
    (
      [ID] INT ,
      [CustomerID] INT ,
      [Name] VARCHAR(5) ,
      [Salary] INT
    );

INSERT  INTO #customer
        ( [ID], [CustomerID], [Name], [Salary] )
VALUES  ( 1, 1, 'John', 3000 ),
        ( 2, 1, 'Kim', 1000 ),
        ( 3, 2, 'Sarah', 2000 ),
        ( 4, 2, 'Jim', 4000 ),
        ( 5, 2, 'Kane', 2000 ),
        ( 6, 3, 'Bul', 2500 );

SELECT  c.* ,
        t.TheCount
FROM    #customer c
        INNER JOIN ( SELECT CustomerID ,
                            COUNT(*) AS TheCount
                     FROM   #customer
                     GROUP BY CustomerID
                   ) t ON t.CustomerID = c.CustomerID

DROP TABLE #customer
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT t.*, c.[Count]
FROM tbl t
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT  CustomerID, Count(1) AS [Count]
    FROM tbl 
    GROUP BY CustomerID 
)c ON t.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
```

Comment: CustomerID is not Foreign Key, SO I do not have 2nd table to put a JOIN on.

Comment: You can consider the second table like a table with the unique keys(customerID). There is no limitations to use JOIN only for FK columns. It works fine. But I agree that the top answer is really good.